# chat layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am trying to create a layout like this (the blue bubble):

[image]

However, in my XML below, the blue bubble extends to the whole width of the fragment though I have specified the width as `wrap_content` everywhere. Any ideas ?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="17dp"
    android:paddingLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bubble_user"  android:gravity="end" android:background="@drawable/chat_user_reply_background"  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_reply_status"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_user_reply"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"


        android:src="@drawable/ic_single_tick"
        android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_reply_timing"
            style="@style/chat_timings"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chat_user_reply"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_reply_status"
            android:text="17:10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_user_reply"
            style="@style/chat_text_message_style"

            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_reply_timing"
            android:maxWidth="280dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="Rahul Agrawal is a good boy but he does not know what he wants." />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<style name="chat_text_message_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/chat_message_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="chat_timings">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Check the size of the image used as the background for RelativeLayout

Comment: Its not a image. Its just a shape drawable with background color and radius

Comment: check the styles of the text views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of the image used as background for RelativeLayout or change the width of the Layout.Using the same xml with 100dp of width.

**UPDATE**
The maxWidth of the TextView adjust it according to design.

It looks like this:[image]